# Code evaluation: is this considered as a bad practice?

Tags: java

Is this code considered as a bad practice ? Does it use more memory than it should?

```
int[] generateCoordinates(){
    return new int[]{
            new Random().nextInt(100),
            new Random().nextInt(100),
            new Random().nextInt(100)
    };
```

Comment: it is a waste of ressources, you dont need 3 instances of the Random class to do that

Comment: `return new Random().ints(3, 0, 100).toArray();` would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it uses more memory than it should, but if you only call `generateCoordinates()` few times, it's wouldn't make much difference.

That said, there's no reason to create multiple instances of `Random` when one instance can serve all your needs:

```
int[] generateCoordinates() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return new int[] {
            random.nextInt(100),
            random.nextInt(100),
            random.nextInt(100)
    };
}
```

And if you call `generateCoordinates()` many times, it would make sense to make `random` an instance variable, since instantiating and garbage collecting a large number of `Random` objects can become costly.